# Problema com join e subconsultas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um exercício para responder, entretanto nao consigo a solução completa, somente ideias parciais, o SGBD utilizado é o SQL Server.

Considerando as tabelas Customers, Orders e Order Details crie uma consulta SQL que traga ID do pedido, a data do pedido, o nome da companhia que fez o pedido e o valor total do pedido.

```
/****** [Customers]    ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerID] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [ContactName] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ContactTitle] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Region] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](24) NULL
);

/****** [Orders]    ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RequiredDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShippedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShipVia] [int] NULL,
    [Freight] [money] NULL,
    [ShipName] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [ShipAddress] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [ShipCity] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ShipRegion] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ShipPostalCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ShipCountry] [nvarchar](15) NULL
);

/****** [Orders Details]    ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order Details](
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [money] NOT NULL 
);
```

O que há de errado com esse código, não consigo achar a solução:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDate, CompanyName, 
       (SELECT OrderID,   SUM([UnitPrice]) 
         FROM [Order Details] 
         GROUP BY OrderID 
         HAVING COUNT(OrderID)=1) AS TOTAL
 FROM Orders
     INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
     INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID;
```

Comment: Não consigo achar o erro, segue o código:
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDate, CompanyName, (SELECT SUM([UnitPrice]) FROM [Order Details])  FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas formas de se obter o resultado. Considerando-se o código que postou, me parece que basta rever o cálculo da totalização de pedido.

A subconsulta

```
  SELECT OrderID,   SUM([UnitPrice]) 
     FROM [Order Details] 
     GROUP BY OrderID 
     HAVING COUNT(OrderID)=1
```

deve ser transformada em uma subcosulta correlacionada

```
  SELECT sum (OD.UnitPrice) 
     from [Order Details] as OD
     where OD.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
```

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Customers.CompanyName, 
      (SELECT sum (OD.UnitPrice) 
         from [Order Details] as OD
         where OD.OrderID = Orders.OrderID) as TOTAL
 from Orders
     inner join Customers on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b964d/7